# implement getIterator method in version 5.x of twilio sdk

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have used following code in twilio version 4.x:

```
$events = $this->client->workspace->events->getIterator(0, 50, array(
            'Minutes' => round((time() - strtotime('today')) / 60),
            'ResourceType' => 'Task'
        ));
```

I have upgraded to version 5.x now. And I am not sure how to use getiterator in version 5.16. I tried several ways and also tried to find solution on internet but could not succeed. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

II got it. It should be done by read method like this:

```
$events = $this->client->taskrouter
            ->workspaces($this->workspaceSid)
            ->events->read(
                array('Minutes' => round((time() - strtotime('today')) / 60),'ResourceType' => 'Task'),
                50
            );
```

I was putting parameter for read method in the other way around so it was not working before.